# Why empty output function string doesn't cover to integer?

Tags: php, function, types, casting, output

Why follow function return 1 (integer):

```
<?php

function f() : int
{
    return '1';
}
```

But call this function:

```
function f() : int
{
    return '';
}
```

will raise error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: Return value of f() must be of the type int, string returned in /Users/alm/test_int.php:5
```

For me logically it should return 0 (integer).
Please send link to php documentation about function output type casting. Thank you!

Comment: '' is an empty string, and that´s never equal to 0

Comment: One thing is - why define the return type as an int and then return a string?  If it's meant to be an int then return it as an int and not just hope that some magic happens and suddenly it takes a string and converts it.

Comment: _Logically it should return 0_: What makes you say that?  I can't see why it would be logical for an implicit type conversion from an empty string to an int to result in `0` as the output.

Comment: An empty string is not a number, and it is not logical for it to be cast to int(0). If you put [`declare(strict_types=1);`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php#functions.arguments.type-declaration.strict) at the top of your file you would not even consider this question. I would recommend to do so to avoid the confusion with implicit type casting in future.

Comment: Check out the section on [`strict typing`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php#functions.arguments.type-declaration) and the explanations leading up to it.

Comment: @nacho it's not true: `echo (int)'';` will by 0 (integer)

Comment: @NigelRen great! follow your logic compiler should raise the error on return *any* string from function. but with '1' it's return 1 (integer)

Comment: See the note about `declare(strict_types=1);`.  But even though it may work - the basic principle is that the return type is there for a reason and not merely as a hint to IDE's.

Comment: @NigelRen so converting types of function output and converting types by (int)"string" are working in different way. Please provide link to the PHP spec with description type cast of function's output.

Answer (score 0):

Although I don't understand your assertion that an implicit conversion from an empty string to an int would result in `0`, you can indeed make that happen using an explicit type conversion.

Consider this code:

```
function f() :  int {
    return '0';
}

function g() :  int {
    return (int)'';
}

function h() :  int {
    return '';
}

echo 'f: ' . f();
echo '<br />';
echo 'g: ' . g();
echo '<br />';
echo 'h: ' . h();
```

Function `g` actually returns an `int` with a value of `0`.  Function `h` does not work (it matches the function in your example).  The output is:

```
f: 0
g: 0
FATAL ERROR Uncaught TypeError: Return value of h() must be of the type integer, string returned in ...
```

So if you did an *explicit cast* as the function returns (i.e. `return (int)'';`) you will get a `0`.

If you wanted to accept a string parameter and then output that as an int, just use the explicit cast again:

```
function f($p) :  int {
    return (int)$p;
}

echo '0: ' . f(0);
echo '<br />';
echo "'0': " . f('0');
echo '<br />';
echo "'': " . f('');
```

Outputs:

```
0: 0
'0': 0
'': 0
```

Comment: Why `return '1';` converting to 1, but `return ''` is raising TypeError, but `echo (int)''`; is 0 when `declare(strict_types=0);`? Please provide link to the PHP specification with description of type casting for this case. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Finally i've found documentation which explaining why '' can't be convert to 0:

> †Non-numeric strings not accepted. Numeric strings with trailing characters are accepted, but produce a notice.

See "Behaviour of weak type checks" in [here](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/scalar_type_hints_v5?s[]=return&s[]=type&s[]=cast)